# Crystal Reports crosstable formatting

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crosstab

My colleague and I have taken over a vb.net project that uses Crystal Reports (I have CR9 on my PC).

The user has given the following feedback to us on how he would like the reports changed.

1) At the moment, it is wasting space by showing empty columns. How is it possible to not show the columns where all values are "-"? (I've tried using Crosstab Expert, however there are some reports where the columns have second sub-columns with titles in, so with these ones it shows them as it treats the columns as not empty)

2) The crosstabs at the moment are displaying from left to right, and are adding next to each other. My user wants the tables to go underneath each other, so that the report goes downwards, rather than sideways. How is this possible?

If anybody knows a fix to either of these issues that would be great, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the empty columns, you can choose a custom style in the Crosstab Expert and select *Suppress Empty Columns*

[image]

If the dashes don't count as empty, you might need to change the crosstab to evaluate a formula which replaces the dashes as zeroes or blanks.

---

I'm not aware of a good way to make a crosstab separate vertically as you specified. But you could swap the rows with the columns. It appears to me you have *way* more columns than you do rows, which should fit better on the  page.

Comment: Hi, as for the suppressing - I have tried this, it works for a lot of reports, however for some of them there are multiple layers of columns (take the one I screenshotted for example, it may be repeated multiple times, but each one has a main column heading of United Kingdom, and then the level 2 columns are the codes seen in the column headings of this tagble), so it doesn't see them as empty, if this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the database field directly in the cross tab which is the reason you are getting `-`. Possible approach would be to write a condition and use that in cross tab. something like below

Create a formula `@Formula1`

```
if {Database.field}<>"-"
then {Database.field} //You can end the condition here if you wish
else "" // If you write else then check option supress empty rows or columns as per requirement
```

Now create a cross tab using `Formula1` and display

Coming to your second problem , If you not wish to spread cross tab horizontally then you can pivote cross tab by `Right click on cross tab` or go to cross tab expert and give the fields that spread in rows part and that are static in column part.

Hope this helps